# Javascript Google Maps Api, multiple markers with links, only geoceder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've got problems to put links on multiple markers, I can show my markers on the map, but when a I try tu put link on them, I have always the same link on all markers, the last. Here I provide a sample code:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 400px; width:100%;"></div>
    <script>
    var markers = [{"name":"Vasto","url":"http://www.google.com"},{"name":"Chieti","url":"http://www.wikipedia.com"}];
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var LatLng;
    var url;
    console.log(markers);

    function initMap() {
        LatLng = {lat: 42.2872297, lng: 13.3403448};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 8, center: LatLng});
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        setMarkers();
    }

    function setMarkers() {
        var marker, i, url;
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            url = markers[i].url;
            geocoder.geocode({'address': markers[i].name}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    window.location.href = url;
                });
            } else {
            /*console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);*/
            }});
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Any solutions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: asynchronous function (geocoder.geocode) inside a for loop ... when will we ever learn - I'm looking for the appropriate duplicate, but can't seem to find it because I've been drunking

Comment: yes ok, but I need geocoder, because I cant' store latlng data, there's a way or an alternative?

Comment: you don't need an alternative - the problem is asynchronous code ... by the time the code in the geocoder.geocode callback is called, the value of `url` is **guaranteed** to be `markers[markers.length - 1].url`

Answer (score 0):

Due to asynchronous code, you need to change your code a bit

```
function setMarkers() {
    markers.forEach(function(item) {
        var url = item.url;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': item.name}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                window.location.href = url;
            });
        } else {
        /*console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);*/
        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that works, I was absolutely HAMMERED when I wrote it